# How to filter and convert multidimensional array to single array php

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [job] => Manager
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dave
            [job] => Staff
        )
)
```

Purpose: I want get detail only from Dave.
How to filter by [name] and then convert to single array.

Filter by name = **Dave** *only
I want output like this:

```
Array
(
      [name] => Dave
      [job] => Staff
)
```

Comment: Could the name `Dave` exist multiple time?

Comment: no, this name is unique.